# Swift and HealthKit: type of expression too ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, healthkit

I want to get my hands on Swift and HealthKit. I'm following
[this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/86336/ios-8-healthkit-swift-getting-started), but I have trouble when asking for HealthKit permissions. I have searched the problem and it's common in the transition to Swift 2, but I only vaguely understand the matter.
Here's the code:

```
let healthKitTypesToRead = Set(arrayLiteral:[
  HKObjectType.characteristicTypeForIdentifier(HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierDateOfBirth),
  HKObjectType.characteristicTypeForIdentifier(HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBloodType),
  HKObjectType.characteristicTypeForIdentifier(HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBiologicalSex),
  HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass),
  HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight),
  HKObjectType.workoutType()
  ])
```

And the error I get is "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context". I actually only need one element, can I skip altogether the array creation then?
I tried to work around it but I'm not able to match the type without getting compiler errors. And yes, I searched on stack overflow yet I've not been able to solve it.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is unable to infer the type from the 3 different types you are passing into the literal `HKCharacteristicType?`, `HKQuantityType?` and `HKWorkoutType`. You need to set the type of the set to `HKObjectType` and explicitly unwrap the optionals if they are guaranteed to return non-nil values. If the values are not guaranteed to exist then it would be best to check each one for `nil` before adding to the set.

```
let healthKitTypesToRead: Set<HKObjectType> = [
    HKObjectType.characteristicTypeForIdentifier(HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierDateOfBirth)!,
    HKObjectType.characteristicTypeForIdentifier(HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBloodType)!,
    HKObjectType.characteristicTypeForIdentifier(HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBiologicalSex)!,
    HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass)!,
    HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight)!,
    HKObjectType.workoutType()
    ]
```